# How did this address steal my Ethereum ERC-20 Tokens using Uniswap? 0x2b5b060d57b1333c9b2739e9c15b039726dd51ec

Tags: erc-20, security, uniswap

I was using my Trust wallet on my mobile and tried to do a swap from ETH to an ERC20 token but realized a day after that it got drained to this account: https://etherscan.io/address/0x2b5b060d57b1333c9b2739e9c15b039726dd51ec#comments

It also seems that this person was able to steal from others too. My main question now is how did this happen?

When I did the swap, I received my ERC-20 tokens, and it was sitting in my account fine. But looking at the blockchain, 5 hours later it moved to this person's wallet. However I bought another ERC20 token and managed to get it out when it arrived. So its safe to assume this "loophole" is done manually and there isn't a bot monitoring my address. Currently my ETH account still has $150 worth of ETH that isn't drained.

So I'm not sure what type of loophole did this hacker is using to steal my ERC20 tokens. Right now the possibilities is either trust wallet or Uniswap is comprised.

Comment: What wallet did you use to carry the Transaction? Are you sure your device is not compromised by malware?? Also did you check if the token had a Approval function??

Comment: how and where do i check this on etherscan? when giving approval function is it only gives approval to send that erc-20 token only and not others? what about ETH itself? does this explain why my still have ETH in my wallet?

Comment: It will be easier to diagnose the problem if the Token Smart contract is known.

Comment: This was the transaction that stole the token: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf6a4db42ec6e26d001400d63182b13d4eee7ba0f93558aeb43f49e4ab0d7804c

Comment: Here's Etherscan's approval checker for your address (looks like only USDC has been approved): https://etherscan.io/tokenapprovalchecker?search=0xc4dd6541a56c433b970033c0c13ad416bfeb491b

Comment: How did you create your address/private key? Did you create it in Trust Wallet itself, or did you import it from somewhere?

Comment: it was in trust wallet already. so does this mean trust wallet is the issue? and not because I gave approval to a token? the polkastarter token was stolen, but i am still unsure how this happened.

Comment: They were physhing and they caught you? They pretended to be from the website and you possibly gave them your 12 word recovery phrase?

Comment: hey i want fake token which has value in trust wallet but has no exchange to convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibles reasons that this happened and I will try to list them all.

First of all, the [problematic transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf6a4db42ec6e26d001400d63182b13d4eee7ba0f93558aeb43f49e4ab0d7804c) called the `transfer()` function on the POLS token contract, not the `transferFrom()` function.  It means that this fraud has nothing to do with the approval you made earlier to Uniswap. The transaction must have been signed either by you or by someone who has access to your private key.

Possible reasons:

1. You made this transfer transaction yourself thinking that you were making another transaction, possibly through a phishing website.
2. You lost your private key or mnemonic. For instance, you stored it insecurely or on a compromised device, you entered it on a phishing wallet (fake wallet that sends your mnemonic to the scammer), you uploaded it on github by mistake or anywhere public, etc.
3. Your phone where you keep your wallet is seriously compromised.
4. There is a very serious issue with Trust Wallet. However, from the comments on etherscan it seems that some may have use Metamask and not Trust Wallet. Also, many more users of Trust Wallet would have been affected if it was a problem with Trust Wallet.

My advice would be to create a new wallet (new mnemonic) on a different device and transfer everything you have to that new address. Assume that all the devices you used are compromised.

Comment: Its safe to say # 2, 3 and 4 is out of the question since my wallet still has ETH in it untouched. If I did lose my seed, I'd imagine everything would be gone and not just specific tokens.

Comment: You'd be surprised - it would seem to me from a few cases I know about that often the hacker (or bot) just grabs some stuff and isn't too particular about sweeping out everything. Thing is, if the hacker is good with automation, they can theoretically monitor the address to see if you try moving out anything else and outbid you. Contact a professional before trying to move anything still in the address imho.

Comment: who is a "professional" in this space?

Comment: This: https://docs.flashbots.net/whitehat/  Be very careful to not fall for impersonators that may try to scam you.